# XMLReader -- Getting problem with utf characters

Tags: php, xml, encoding, utf-8, windows-1252

I am parsing a huge xml file and encoding of file is to be said
**< ? xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>**bold**

The db encoding is utf8 and I am running this query before anything is saved to db
    $sql='SET NAMES "utf8" COLLATE "utf8_swedish_ci"';

What the problem is that sometimes some non standard characters comes in the xml file like
Lycka™ : roman
I know that trademark symbol is from windows-1252 encoding.

Im using php. I have tried utf8_encode.

here is saved in db [image] and

here is the output in browser [image]

I want it to converted to utf, that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code and worked fine

```
function cp1252_to_utf8($str) 
{

        $cp1252_map = array(
                "\xc2\x80" => "\xe2\x82\xac", /* EURO SIGN */
                "\xc2\x82" => "\xe2\x80\x9a", /* SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK */
                "\xc2\x83" => "\xc6\x92",     /* LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH HOOK */
                "\xc2\x84" => "\xe2\x80\x9e", /* DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK */
                "\xc2\x85" => "\xe2\x80\xa6", /* HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS */
                "\xc2\x86" => "\xe2\x80\xa0", /* DAGGER */
                "\xc2\x87" => "\xe2\x80\xa1", /* DOUBLE DAGGER */
                "\xc2\x88" => "\xcb\x86",     /* MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT */
                "\xc2\x89" => "\xe2\x80\xb0", /* PER MILLE SIGN */
                "\xc2\x8a" => "\xc5\xa0",     /* LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH CARON */
                "\xc2\x8b" => "\xe2\x80\xb9", /* SINGLE LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION */
                "\xc2\x8c" => "\xc5\x92",     /* LATIN CAPITAL LIGATURE OE */
                "\xc2\x8e" => "\xc5\xbd",     /* LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z WITH CARON */
                "\xc2\x91" => "\xe2\x80\x98", /* LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK */
                "\xc2\x92" => "\xe2\x80\x99", /* RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK */
                "\xc2\x93" => "\xe2\x80\x9c", /* LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK */
                "\xc2\x94" => "\xe2\x80\x9d", /* RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK */
                "\xc2\x95" => "\xe2\x80\xa2", /* BULLET */
                "\xc2\x96" => "\xe2\x80\x93", /* EN DASH */
                "\xc2\x97" => "\xe2\x80\x94", /* EM DASH */

                "\xc2\x98" => "\xcb\x9c",     /* SMALL TILDE */
                "\xc2\x99" => "\xe2\x84\xa2", /* TRADE MARK SIGN */
                "\xc2\x9a" => "\xc5\xa1",     /* LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CARON */
                "\xc2\x9b" => "\xe2\x80\xba", /* SINGLE RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION*/
                "\xc2\x9c" => "\xc5\x93",     /* LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE */
                "\xc2\x9e" => "\xc5\xbe",     /* LATIN SMALL LETTER Z WITH CARON */
                "\xc2\x9f" => "\xc5\xb8"      /* LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS*/
        );

        return  strtr(utf8_encode($str), $cp1252_map);
}


$str = cp1252_to_utf8( iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try encoding the string in utf8 before saving to db ? 
For php there is utf8_encode() function, there might be similar functions in the language you are using.

Comment: Im using php.  Ya, I have tried utf8_encode. Here what is saved in db "LyckaÂ : roman" and when I try to decode it, it is shown as  "Lycka : roman "

Comment: I think you will have to use multibyte functions to encode. use mb_convert_encoding()      http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php